# Syncing tab groups in Safari Tech Preview

Tags: safari, tabs, macos

It seems that only Safari is sync tab groups between devices. Safari Technology Preview does not seem to share them.

Is there a trick?  Was it just disabled for STP?

At worst, is there any handy one-off want to bulk transfer tab groups?

The problem: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari Technology Preview 162 enabled tab group syncing.

> Note: Enabled Shared Tab Groups and syncing for Tab Groups, Website Settings, and Web Extensions in this release. These features require Safari Technology Preview 162 or later running on macOS Ventura 13.2 or later, or macOS Monterey with Safari 16.2.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-technology-preview-release-notes/stp-release-162

Answer (score 0):

Tab syncing seems to be disabled in [most releases](https://developers.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/) of Safari Technology Preview, including [most recent](https://webkit.org/blog/12998/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-149/).